# Is there any way to execute 64-bit programs on a 32-bit computer?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

Just a simple question: Is there any way to run a program compiled under a 64 bit Windows environment (with mingw64) on a 32 bit machine? Any DLL or any compatibility layer which I can use?

Comment: You really should say "compiled for a 64-bit environment", as you could certainly compile a program for a 32-bit target, under a 64-bit environment. For example, if you run 64-bit Lazarus/FreePascal on Windows7/64, you could compile FOR either a 64 or 32-bit target platform.  Nitpicky, but semantics counts here.  Also, you need to specify whether "32-bit computer" means 32-bit processor, 32-bit hardware, or both.

Answer (score 5):

If you are talking about a 32-bit processor, then no. But if you are running a 32-bit OS on 64-bit hardware, then you can do it with VMWare.  A 64-bit guest can run on a 32-bit host, if the hardware supports it.

Comment: you could argue that is a 64 bit system but it's an imaginitive idea.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot do this. The other direction is possible through an emulator, e.g. on Windows it is called WOW64.

It is standard practise on platforms that still have large install base of the 32-bit versions of the OS to ship either just a 32-bit version, or both 32- and 64-bit versions.

Answer (score 1):

Bochs should do the trick, but you'd need another copy of Windows to run in the virtual machine.  (Some editions of Windows include additional licenses for virtual machines, so you might be in luck.)

Performance would probably be very poor.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend **VirtualBox** for this purpose, you can download the free version and it's easier to use than VMWare. However you will need a 64bit installation CDROM, and storage space for a full system install, and if you are installing Microsoft Windows they will expect you to pay for a license key.

Also your CPU needs to support both 64 bit mode in the hardware, and the vt-X/AMD-V features (most of them do). It's a bit slower, although mostly that seems to be the display that slows it down, not the internal program calculations. This is NOT an emulation, the CPU is really running native 64 bit, but VirtualBox fakes the hardware devices (display, disk, network, etc) so the result is not as nice as running normally. 3D graphics acceleration is available, but it has limitations.

An easier option is simply to **hire an online Virtual Machine** by searching for someone offering 64 bit versions of Windows Server (there are plenty). Usually they will offer connection over Remote Desktop, typically you can pay by the month. Upload your programs, run what you want, then delete it when you are finished and cancel the service. The service provider handles installation, licensing, hardware, etc.

Answer (score -1):

hey that was a problem that gave me a headache for a while but i solved it. I had windows 10 32 bit but when i opened system in control panel it said that "32 bit architecture, 64 bit processor." lookup some websites and your hardware must have a few things which you can check in CPU-Z( lookup some webpages for this) its necessary. Then export your folders,documents, softwares in an external hard drive..now download the windows 10 64 bit iso file and boot it.ands viola! you got 64 bit architecture ( i also recommend upgrading ram atleast minimum 4 gb) or the other way is to install 64 bit guest in VMware ir another virtual machine software...gud luck

Comment: this is just reinstalling Windows 64-bit.

Answer (score -3):

No, It is not possible...........