# Eclipse: "Could not reserve enough space"

Tags: java, eclipse, memory-management

So I'm doing a minecraft mod in java in eclipse and any time I wanted to start it in eclipse for testing it doesn't work and I get the following output:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated  and will likely be removed in a future release
```

What can I do? Obviously this problem is not about the RAM not being there, I've got 6GB, it's about java not being allowed to take it.

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit JVM? It may fail to allocate 1G of _contiguous_ address space for the heap.

Comment: My OS is 32bit. As for the jvm I'm not sure, how would I check that?

Comment: You can't run a 64-bit JVM on a 32-bit O.S., nor can you use over 4GB (3GB in some cases) of physical memory without switching to 64-bit.

Comment: You just won't be able to work around this on your 32bit OS. You have hit a brick wall.

Comment: Is it possible that I use a 64bit jvm and eclipse works fine when not actually running the code?

So there's nothing I can do?

Comment: It is *impossible* (well, [mostly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7206675/2825369)) to run 64-bit applications on a 32-bit OS. Your IDE runs fine because it's only displaying the code, not running a compiled version of it. (Just seeing the code doesn't require allocating the memory it would want if it were ran.)

Comment: I think I will get myself some 64bit-Linux. For programming minecraft it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Just try setting a slightly lower value. E.g. Debug Configurations, Program Arguments:  -Xmx800M